# Multistart does not produce all optimal points

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to solve

```
min f(x) s.t. x in X
```

where

1) `f(x)` has more than one local minimum

2) `f(x)` is smooth and I can compute the gradient of `f(x)`

3) `X` is a compact subset of `R`

I use `MultiStart` in `MatLab` to find all local minima of `f(x)`.  According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-globalsearch-and-multistart-work.html) on comparing `GlobalSearch` and `MultiStart` it appears to me that we can use `MultiStart` to find ALL local minima.  However, when I run a simple test function, `MultiStart` only outputs a global minimum and the value of the function at the global minimum.   My question is this:  using `MultiStart`, how do I obtain all minima?

My example is `f(x) = x^4 - x^2 + 1` with `X=[-10,10]`.  On `X`, `f(x)` has two local minima: `x* = 2^{-0.5}` and `x* = -2^{-0.5}`.  Both are actually global minima, and `f(x*) =0.75`.  My sample code is below.  `Multistart` only outputs `x* = 2^{-0.5}` (with initial value `x0 = 1`) and does not output `x* = -2^{-0.5}`.  Is there a way to output both solutions?

```
ms = MultiStart;
ms.Display = 'iter';
options_fmincon = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','off','GradObj','on','GradConstr','off','Algorithm','sqp');
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',@(x)test_function(x),'x0',1,'lb',-10,'ub',10,'options',options_fmincon);
[x_multi,val_multi]= run(ms,problem,50)

function [val,grad] = test_function(x)
val = x^4-x^2+1;
if nargout>1
    grad = 4*x^3-2*x;
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: the set of local minima found via MultiStart is in the fifth output argument of `run(MultiStart,problem,50)`.

There are more than two output variables for `run(MultiStart,problem,50)`.  In particular, there are five outputs:

```
[out1,out2,out3,out4,out5] = run(MultiStart,problem,50)
```

where

`out1` is the best local minima -- it is the one that maximizes `f(x)` out of the set of local minima that the program found

`out2` is the value of the objective function at `out`: `out2 = f(out1)`

`out3` is an exit flag that tells us why our program converged/failed to converge

`out4` lists information about number of iterations ect.

`out5` is a structure containing all relevant output information, including a list of the local minima that the program found.